# How to use popUpToSaveState and restoreState to save and keep state in Navigation Component Android Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, navigation, savestate

I am using [Navigation Component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation) to handle navigations, but when use `popBackStack()` or `onBackPressed()` to back to previous fragment my `onViewCreated` call again in fragment with api and set up views.
Since [Navigation Component 2.4](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#back-stack) unveiled new features ([popUpToSaveState and restoreState](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.4.0-alpha01)), i want to use it. please tell me how?

Comment: You still need to use the [Fragment APIs to save your state](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/saving-state); `onViewCreated()` being called is still expected.

Comment: @reza_khalafi Have you solved this?

Comment: Any updates....?

Comment: @木大白易 I think you should use SharedViewModel. SaveState doesn't good idea.

Answer (score -2):

Even though you save your state **onViewCreated** will be called.

you need to use to save state.

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
}
```

and restore it on **onCreate**.